# How to change the location of Viber downloads folder

Tags: settings, viber

Files transferred by Viber are stored on `~/Documents/ViberDownloads` by default. How is it possible to change the destination to a location under `~/Downloads`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a complimentary answer to AliNa's.

If you want to move your previously downloaded files to the new location follow below steps:

1. Backup your downloaded files
2. Backup `.ViberPC` folder
3. Open `~/.ViberPC/{your-phone-number}/viber.db` with sqliteman
4. Paste below query to query edit area:

   `Update messages set PayloadPath = replace(PayloadPath, "Documents/ViberDownloads", ".viberdownloads") where PayloadPath is not null and PayloadPath <> '';`

What this does is; replaces text `Documents/ViberDownloads` with `.viberdownloads` in `PayloadPath` field of `messages` table. I typed ".viberdownloads" because I wanted my downloads in /home/user/.viberdownloads folder. Change these strings according to your use.

5. Click Run(F9)

Make sure you carefully backup `.ViberPC` folder, if something goes wrong you will lose all your message history on this machine.

Answer (score 6):

Viber preferences are stored as ".db" files under `~/.ViberPC/`. You should have installed an extra application in order to open or edit them; for example, [Sqliteman](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/sqliteman) which is available from Software Center.

To edit the location of downloads folder, open the following file:

```
~/.ViberPC/{your-phone-number}/viber.db
```

On the left sidebar of Sqliteman, open **Tables** > **Settings**. You can see the setting entitled **DownloadFolder** on the bottom right. Double click on its value to change the location as you wish.

[image: Sqliteman window]

If you have downloaded some files before you change the setting, you won't be able to open them from Viber afterwards. To solve this, @HeyYo have a great answer.

Comment: If the table to the right doesn't show up, enter in the textbox above it the following query: `SELECT * FROM settings;` (then press the green play button and wait a bit). Next, if double-clicking the table cell doesn't allow to change its value, enter in the same top textbox the following query: `UPDATE settings SET SettingValue="/path/to/new/directory" WHERE SettingTitle="DownloadFolder";`.

Comment: This seems to no longer work in newer versions :(.

Comment: Same here, doesn't work anymore in the current versions. Does anyone know? Please? :)

Answer (score 2):

In OSX you can find `ViberPC` folder here `/Users/<Username>/Library/Application Support/ViberPC`

Answer (score 1):

The above didn't work for me (in version 6.5.5), so I temporarily fixed it by hacking the main viber binary, the **sed** below replaces **ViberDownloads** with **.viberDownload**:

```
sudo -i
cd /opt/viber
cp -a Viber Viber.original
hexdump -ve '1/1 "%.2X"' Viber.original | sed "s/5669626572446F776E6C6F616473/2E7669626572446F776E6C6F6164/g" | xxd -r -p > Viber
```

Comment: You could probably do `sudo sed -i.original 's/ViberDownloads/.viberDownload/g' /opt/viber/Viber`; the string exists as-is in the executable.

Comment: Yes, the straight `sed` works too.
Note to anyone attempting this: the replacement string must not be longer than the original. But it can be shorter, just pad with NULLs.

Comment: I made it to use `~/Downloads/V` (referred as `~/Documents/../Downloads/V`) instead of `~/Documents/ViberDownloads` by invoking `sudo sed -i.original 's/ViberDownloads/..\/Downloads\/V/g' /opt/viber/Viber`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be just making a symbolic link:

```
cd ~/Documents
mv ViberDownloads /SomeOtherLocation
ln -s /SomeOtherLocation/ViberDownloads
```

I also moved ~/.ViberPC to other drive in the same way.

The benefit is that the location of the folders can be changed easily when needed without updating the database.